# RuboCop: enforce empty lines surrounding block?

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I would like to get RuboCop to enforce a style like this:

```
# bad

alias_method :pharmacy, :recipient
alias_method :pharmacy=, :recipient=
before_save -> do
  self.label = "Prescription" if label.blank?
end
before_save -> do
  self.recipient ||= appointment.patient.pharmacy
end

# good

alias_method :pharmacy, :recipient
alias_method :pharmacy=, :recipient=

before_save -> do
  self.label = "Prescription" if label.blank?
end

before_save -> do
  self.recipient ||= appointment.patient.pharmacy
end
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a solution?

Comment: Sadly no. It looks like it will probably require a custom cop.

Comment: That's so strange, there's a cop for empty lines around the inside of a block (EmptyLinesAroundBlockBody), but not the outside, which seems far more useful.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is possible.
There is a way to extend the Rubocop rule set by using extensions
https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/extensions.html.